# How to return an error message string

Tags: c++, string, error-handling

I have written a driver in C++ for a peripheral device and in short, there is a number of errors that can occur during interaction. I have defined error codes for all the possible errors. I want to write a method that enables the user to query the meaning of error code.

Bear in mind that I have a total of 17 possible errors. The corresponding messages are of varying lengths.

I have solved it with a function that accepts the error code and returns a string with the error message. The function uses the error code to loop through a switch case routine each case returning a different error message as shown below.

```
std::string getErrorMessage(int errorCode)
{
    std::string errorMessage = "no error" ;

    switch(errorCode) {
    case 0:
        errorMessage = "no error" ;
        break ;
    case 10:
        errorMessage = "there is a network error" ;
        break ;
    case 40:
        errorMessage = "there is a network or protocol error" ;
        break ;
    default:
        errorMessage = "unknown error" ;
    }

    return errorMessage ;
}
```

This function works, but it's not a "pretty" solution. Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions for a better solution?

Comment: hint: this function **maps** integer to string values.

Comment: I see that this is the least of your problems, but you might spend a minute thinking about internationalization, i.e. different error messages for different locales. Far too much software out there doesn't give a damn...

Comment: I normally use this method or a map.

Comment: why not to use standard system error codes, and get the description with `strerror(errCode)`?

Answer (score 5):

If your error number is not large, using a table is more efficient

```
char *error[SIZE] = 
 {
   [0] = "NO error",
   [10] = "there is a network error",
   [40] = "there is a network or protocol error",
    ....
}
```

You need some defensive check to make sure the error number is in range.

This is how glibc implments strerror() as I can recall.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `std::map<int, std::string>` for mapping error messages to according codes:

```
std::string getErrorMessage(int errorCode)
{
    static std::map<int, std::string> codes;
    static bool initialized = false;
    if (!initialized) {
        codes[0]    = "No error.";
        codes[10]   = "Network error.";
        codes[40]   = "Network or protocol error.";
        initialized = true;
    }
    if (codes.count(errorCode) > 0)
        return codes[errorCode];
    return "Unknown error.";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If your error codes are sparse, the switch is probably the best
solution.  If you can make them dense, however, then you can
just put the error messages in a table and use the error code to
index into it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a map to store the errors and initialize them in one place for everyone to see:

```
std::map<int,std::string> error_codes;
void init_codes()
{
    error_codes[1231] = "error 1";
    error_codes[121231] = "error 2";
    error_codes[131231] = "error 3";
    error_codes[135] = "error 4";
    error_codes[10] = "error 5";
    error_codes[0] = "error 6";
}

std::string get_error(const int e)
{
    auto i = error_codes.find(e);
    if( i != error_codes.end() )
    {
        //error was found
        return (*i).second;
    }
    else
    {
        return "Unknown error";
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side note the error codes can be even read from a file and added to the map

Answer (score 1):

If the error message are fixed, you are probably better off returning a `const char*`.
It's a lot more efficient, involves no memory allocation and is convertible to a `std::string` if necessary.

```
const char* getErrorMessage(int errorCode)
{
    switch (errorCode) {
        case 0: return "no error";
        case 10: return "there is a network error";
        case 40: return "there is a network or protocol error";
        default: return "unknown error";
    }
}
```